# Outlook 2007 VBA to simulate key strokes

Tags: vba, outlook, keystroke

I am trying to create VBA code to simulate pressing the down arrow key twice, then the delete key twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for SendKeys.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/outlook-help/HV080806799.aspx

http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html

SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DEL}{DEL}"

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.